# Difference between Microsoft's and Monotype's Times New Roman fonts?

Tags: fonts, font-design

The font named `Times New Roman` is trademarked by [Monotype](http://www.monotype.com/about), but the font is licensed to Microsoft (perhaps to others too?). These two fonts (MS TNR & Mo TNR) are clearly different in their coverage. Version 6.85 of MS TNR (bundled with Windows 8.1) contains according to [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html) 4,098 glyphs, whereas Mo TNR according to [their own website](http://catalog.monotype.com/font/monotype/times-new-roman/regular) has only 631 glyphs.

But with respect to the glyphs they actually share, are these two fonts any different at all?

Answer (score 1):

> *...but the font is licensed to Microsoft (perhaps to others too?)*

It is licensed to anyone who bought the license:

> Times New Roman is a serif typeface commissioned by the British
>   newspaper The Times in 1931, created by Victor Lardent at the English
>   branch of Monotype. It was commissioned after Stanley Morison had
>   written an article criticizing The Times for being badly printed and
>   typographically antiquated. The font was supervised by Morison and
>   drawn by Victor Lardent, an artist from the advertising department of
>   The Times. Morison used an older font named Plantin as the basis for
>   his design, but made revisions for legibility and economy of space.
>   Morison's revision became known as Times New Roman and made its debut
>   in the 3 October 1932 issue of The Times newspaper. **After one year,
>   the design was released for commercial sale**.

---

> *But with respect to the glyphs they actually share, are these two
>   fonts any different at all?*

In the links you provided, you are comparing whole [Times New Roman Family](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1953) to the [Times New Roman Regular](http://catalog.monotype.com/font/monotype/times-new-roman/regular). If you take a close look you will notice that the Unicode ranges/blocks differ (TNR Regular does not provide Arabic, Hebrew, Cyrilic, etc. characters).

There exist a few different TNR variants, since already Microsoft's naming "Times New Roman" is in reality TrueType version of Times New Roman PS, a narrower variant of Monotype's classic Times New Roman typeface.

However to answer your question directly - the two font's you compare have the same glyphs, just that you compare the whole family to a single subset.

Comment: Under the assumption that by "have the same glyphs" you mean that the glyphs are drawn identically, could I ask for some elaboration on this claim? I.e. what is the claim based on? My interpretation of the oft cited piece by Charles Bigelow (http://www.truetype-typography.com/articles/times.htm) is that the licensees could (and did) change the fonts.